# How to add this feature?

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: Picture]

Recently I started learning WPF and I want to make something that I am not sure how it's done.
Basically I want the text that has the red color to be green while its application is opened and red when closed. Help will be much appreciated.
I tried this but didn't work mostly because the whole application stops until the program closes and for some reason will change the color of the text-only if I display a message box

```
private void ColorChangeHandler(Process process, TextBlock textBlock)
    {
        textBlock.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
        MessageBox.Show("Green");
        process.WaitForExit();
        textBlock.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
        MessageBox.Show("Red");
    }
```

Comment: How can any part of the application be "a color" if it is closed?

Comment: Your application "stops" because your main thread is now waiting for the other process to stop. Try to use the [`Exited`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exited?view=netcore-3.1) event of the `process` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Make your handler async and use the [async version of WaitForExit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexitasync?view=net-5.0).

```
private async Task ColorChangeHandler(Process process, TextBlock textBlock)
{
    textBlock.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
    await process.WaitForExitAsync();
    textBlock.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
}
```

Comment: I got the error CS1061 to this "await process.WaitForExitAsync();" could you help me fix it?